# Javascript regular expression single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

My Regex is:

```
var re = /^[a-z A-Z._]{1,15}$/;
```

I want to allow this: `'` (Single Quote).

How can I do this?

Comment: This regex literal looks incorrect. The `[` isn't closed. What pattern do you want here?

Comment: [ has meaning.  and if you want it literaly you should put a \ in front of it...

Comment: it will help people if you show some examples of stuff it should match as well as a sample of what it should not match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following regex for example to allow a string like `abcd'dfgh`:

```
/^[A-Za-z\/\']+[A-Za-z]$/
```

Comment: The regex now accepts slashes, doesn't accept spaces underscores nor dots anymore, doesn't validate that the string is 15 chars at most and now require the string to be 2 chars at least. Also `'` won't be matched if it is the last char. Why the hell was this accepted and upvoted to +4?

Answer (score 1):

To allow single quote, add it in the character class like `^[a-z A-Z._']{1,15}$`

This regex allows `'` matching `'abc'_`, `a'b'c_` etc.

Comment: @mosh In which part do you want to include `'`? Is it like the sample I gave?

Comment: downvoted.  question is for javascript.  you must escape the single quote.

Comment: @ZagNut that is incorrect. [Here](https://ideone.com/L8sOnT)'s an example of a regex replace where the regex contains unescaped single quotes. Aside from regex meta-characters, in JS only forward slashes need to be delimited if you're using the `/pattern/flags` construct, or double quotes if you're using the `RegExp("pattern", flags)` constructor, in both case because they delimit the pattern.

Comment: Err, I should be careful not to make mistakes when correcting others... Since strings can be represented enclosed in single-quotes in JS, you can use `new RegExp('pattern', flags)` to create regexs, in which case single-quotes should be escaped in the pattern ([example](https://ideone.com/ZqhDpL)). This is to my knowledge the only case where it makes sense to escape single quotes in JS regex.