# How to properly escape a single quote?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex to validate email addresses:

```
var content = /^([\w._+-]|(<?))+[a-zA-Z0-9]@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9\_]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,}))$/;
```

I need to allow for `'` before the @ symbol, so [per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379254/1189566) I updated my regex to be such:

```
var content = /^([\w._+-/\']|(<?))+[a-zA-Z0-9]@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9\_]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,}))$/;
```

Note the addition of `/\'` to the first capture block.

However, I'm now able to save data with a `/` in it when that should not be allowed. If I try simply just adding a `'` to the capture block, this throws an 'invalid regex' error.

How do you escape a single quote character without allowing forward slashes?

Edit: For the discussion in the comments, here is a screenshot:

[image]

The first is Visual Studio error

The second is the line in the Chrome debugger

The third is the exception that gets thrown when I step over the creation of the regex.

Comment: why did you add a forward slash?

Comment: Yep, I think the forward slash needs to be removed. Have you tried that @sab669?

Comment: `\'` Visual Studio says 'invalid character set'

Comment: Oh I just realized in that post I quoted, the answer added `\/\'`, not just `/\'` :(

Comment: Why would you need to escape it? `'` has no specific meaning in regex nor in the `/pattern/flag` JS syntax. You only need to escape a character when you want to represent the literal character rather than the meaning it has as a meta-character, e.g. if you want to represent a dot you have to use `\.` because `.` is a meta-character that means "any character"

Comment: Yes single quote is not a special metacharacter in JavaScript regular expression syntax. `/'/` is a valid regex that matches one single quote.

Comment: Note that you have an unescaped minus right in front of it. You need to escape that minus or position it at the end of the character class again. Otherwise it opens a range from `+` to whatever you added next, `/` in this case.

Comment: Please see the screenshot I just editted in. Chrome/Javascript is throwing an exception if I simply add just a `'` to my regex.

Comment: As Sebastian said, `-` is a special character in `[` `]` and needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianProske; this was the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to escape the single quote inside a regex literal.

The issue in your case is the `-` that ends your character class. If it is positioned at the end, it serves as a literal `-` while it opens a range when used in between two characters.

Your current attempt opens that range between `+` and `/`, including `,` and `-`.
If you directly use the `'`, the range is invalid, as `'` has a lower index than `+`.

To solve this, either escape the minus `\-` or move it to the end again.

Comment: Obvious in hindsight :) Thanks again